# How to replace an unknown-substring in a string with specific pattern using Java code?

Tags: java, string, replace

I deal with many strings whose pattern is similar `"string1 src="arbitrary string" string2"` and I want to replace the `"arbitrary string"` with specific string (let's say `"stackoverflow"`)
using Java code.

For example, change these strings:

```
String string1 = "text1 src="arbitrary_string_1" text2"

String string2 = "text3 src="arbitrary_string_2" text4"
```

to:

```
string1 = "text1 src="stackoverflow" text2"

string2 = "text3 src="stackoverflow" text4"
```

I tried several codes using substring() function like:

```
String string1 = "text1 src=\"arbitrary string\" text2" \\declaration of string1

Sting newString = string1.substring(0,indexOf("src")) + "src=\"stackoverflow\"" \\trying of the replacement
```

but it clearly cuts the ending of the string "code".

I also thought about the option of replacement using the pattern of the strings I deal with, but I dont know how to do that..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `String.replace` not what you need?

Comment: I kind of want to replace the "arbitrary_strings" without even knowing what they are.. and in the replace() method I need to specify which word I want to replace. Thanks for the comment. @lexicore

Comment: Still, you need to define what you actually want to replace. @Schred has somehow deducted you want to replace the inner part of the string between `"`` and following `"`. I think you can describe it as a regex and the simply `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
public static String replaceAbitrary(String input, String replacement) {
    // The input up to the first ". If you don't want to include the " in you
    // result, remove the +1
    String start = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('"') + 1);

    // The input starting from the last ". If you don't want to include the ", add a
    // +1
    String end = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf('"'));

    // Put it all together
    return start + replacement + end;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // The input. Note that this system even allows quotation marks inside the
    // arbitrary string.
    String input = "text1 src=\"arbitrary \"string\"\" text2";

    // The string to put instead of the arbitrary one.
    String replacement = "stackoverflow";

    System.out.println(replaceAbitrary(input, replacement));
}
```

This outputs `text1 src="stackoverflow" text2`. If you don't want the quotation marks included, follow the instructions inside the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot!It seems to be what I wanted to do.